# Prove convergence of geometric sequence without Bernoulli's inequality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there an elegant way of proving the convergence of $|q|^n$ for $|q| < 1$ or the divergence of $|q|^n$ for $|q| > 1$ that does not use $(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$ for $x \in [-1; \infty)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

(I couldn't figure out a way to do it and wondered whether there is something I'm missing, or whether maybe Bernoulli's inequality is one of those fundamental things without which we can do very little.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $0<x<1$. Then, $\{x_n=x^n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, and hence has a limit $L$. Now, this limit satisfies $xL=L$ (since $L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n+1}$ as well.) So, $L=0$.

Similarly, if $x>1$ then $\{x_n=x^n\}$ is an increasing sequence, and hence a limit $L$. This also satisfies $xL=L$ which implies that either $L=0$, or $L=\infty$. Since the sequence is increasing, so $L \geq x >1$, so $L= \infty$.

Comment: I like this one; is $xL = L$ a fixpoint thing? I don't really see how it follows from $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n = \lim_{n\to \infty}x^{n+1}$ since the $N$ from the convergence definition differs for both sequences.

Comment: @G.Bach: it's easier than that: note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x^{n+1}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x.(x^n)=x\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x^n$ as $x$ is a fixed number.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite a bit simpler than I had thought.

Comment: @G.Bach: You are welcome. Glade to be of help. I must say- this is the first time that I thought about this limit question- without using Bernoulli's inequality- so I learnt too from your question :).

Answer (score 2):

In the first case: Without using much technology one can observe that the sequence $|q|^n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ so must converge to its infimum. If that infimum were $\lambda > 0$ then pick $n$ such that $|q|^n < \lambda/|q|$ (possible since $\lambda/|q|>\lambda$). Now $|q|^{n+1}<\lambda$, a contradiction.

A similar argument works in the second case, using the fact that if the sequence converges to a finite value then it converges to the supremum of the values $|q|^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Use logarithms. Result follows immediately.

---

If $|q| < 1$, then $\log |q| = k < 0 $. Then $\log |q^n| = \log |q|^n = n \log |q| = nk$ (logarithm rules).
Hence $\lim \log |q^n| = - \infty$ and thus $ \lim |q^n| = 0 $ (continuity of the logarithm function).

The same applies to $|q| > 1$.

Comment: But some of the properties of logarithm that you use are typically proved with the help of Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I added my approach. Can you clarify which parts need Bernoulli's inequality? I think it just uses logarithm rules, and continuity of logarithms.